# Use CSS to grey out options

Tags: html, css

I have the code below.  Currently it hides the input boxes, I want to show them but grey them out and disable, any ideas?

```
<style label="hideElements" name="question.element">
  <![CDATA[
    \@if this.groups
      \@if col.group and row.group
        <td headers="${ec.this.label + "_" + ec.col.label if ec.col.label else ""} $(this.label)_$(col.group.label) $(this.label)_$(row.group.label)" class="element $(extraClasses) $(col.group.styles.ss.groupClassNames) $(col.styles.ss.colClassNames) $(row.styles.ss.rowClassNames) survey-q-grid-cell"  $(extra)>
        </td>
      \@else
        \@if col.group
          <td headers="${ec.this.label + "_" + ec.col.label if ec.col.label else ""} $(this.label)_$(col.group.label)" class="element $(extraClasses) $(col.group.styles.ss.groupClassNames) $(col.styles.ss.colClassNames) $(row.styles.ss.rowClassNames) survey-q-grid-cell"  $(extra)>
          </td>
        \@else
          \@if row.group
            <td headers="${ec.this.label + "_" + ec.col.label if ec.col.label else ""} $(this.label)_$(row.group.label)" class="element $(extraClasses) $(row.group.styles.ss.groupClassNames) $(col.styles.ss.colClassNames) $(row.styles.ss.rowClassNames) survey-q-grid-cell"  $(extra)>
            </td>
          \@else
            <td headers="${ec.this.label + "_" + ec.col.label if ec.col.label else ""}" class="element $(extraClasses) $(col.styles.ss.colClassNames) $(row.styles.ss.rowClassNames) survey-q-grid-cell"  $(extra)>
            </td>
          \@endif
        \@endif
      \@endif
    \@else
      <td headers="${ec.this.label + "_" + ec.col.label if ec.col.label else ""}" class="element $(extraClasses) $(col.styles.ss.colClassNames) $(row.styles.ss.rowClassNames) survey-q-grid-cell"  $(extra)>
      </td>
    \@endif
  ]]>
  </style>

<style copy="hideElements" cols="c2" rows="r7,r8" name="question.element"/>
```

Comment: I have never seen this type of syntax before, how is the CDATA being processed?

Comment: `<input type="text" disabled>` you mean something like this?

Comment: This rooted in a online survey software tool which creates online surveys, so it includes some proprietary code, but also CSS, so was hoping that someone could look at it and help me figure it out.  Yes, I want to disable text.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what syntax you are using but the html output should be:

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="text goes here"/>
```

[here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffh8hzhn/)

Comment: This rooted in a online survey software tool which creates online surveys, so it includes some proprietary code, but also CSS, so was hoping that someone could look at it and help me figure it out. Yes, I want to disable text.